# send a value with onclick on a image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send a value using image and onclick for js. but my function is not working because i can't define value in img tag maybe then how can i send this value to my function.It must show image and when i click image it will send a constent value to a js function.
It's something like

```
    <img src="img/sit.png" value="<?php echo $data[1];>"onclick="choose(this.value);"/>
```

I used js

```
     function choose(idval){
     alert(get.ElementById(idval));
     }
```

But it is not working

The value may use for ajax in js give example if you can.

please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>thumbs</title>
<script>
function sendimg(a)
{
window.location.href='b.html#id='+a.id+'&src='+a.src;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="imgs/img1.jpg" id="img1" onClick="sendimg(this);">
<img src="imgs/img2.jpg" id="img2" onClick="sendimg(this);">
</body>
</html>
```

**Image HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>img</title>
 <script>
 function getimg()
 {
  var a=window.location.href.split('#')[1].split('&'),
  id=a[0].split('=')[1],
  src=a[1].split('=')[1],
  img=document.images[0];
  img.id=id;
  img.src=src;
  }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onLoad="getimg()">
 <img src="ablankimage.gif">
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<img id="catImage" src="http://i.imgur.com/Mmfl8.png" width="100px" value="42" />
<div id="catImageValue"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var catImage = document.getElementById("catImage"),
    catImageValue = document.getElementById("catImageValue");

catImage.onclick = function () {
    catImageValue.innerHTML = "Value = " + catImage.getAttribute("value");
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/6K2bp/ `<=` Click on the cat!

Answer (score 0):

Use data-attributes along with jquery

```
<img id="myImg" src="img/sit.png" data-myvalue="<?php echo $data[1];?>" onclick="doSomething();"/>
```

and then with jQuery in your doSomething() method you can get the value like this:

```
 $("#myImg").data("myvalue")
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting `data-` attribute. -1 for insisting on jquery :P

Comment: No insistence. Just a suggestion. There's several ways to skin a cat. I love JQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<img src="img/sit.png" value="somevalue" onclick="choose(this);"/>
<script>

function choose(element){
    alert(element.getAttribute("value"));
} 
</script>
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FC6sq/1/